# PHP DOMDocument innerText

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

How would I go about adding text into an XML element? For example:

```
<videoTitle>I want to add text here</videoTitle>
```

I have created the DOMDocument, and begun adding the elements. Here is the element that I need to add the text to.

```
$title = $vitals->appendChild($X->createElement("title"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`DOMDocument::createTextNode`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createtextnode.php)

```
$text = $X->createTextNode('Some text here');
$title->appendChild($text);
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the shortcut syntax of [`DOMNode::$nodeValue`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue):

```
$title->nodeValue = 'Some text here';
```

You have to remember with this technique that `nodeValue` sets the text content, not the XML content.  Tags are escaped, not parsed.

Comment: Hello, great, thanks. BTW, is there some way in PHP to automatically add <![CDATA[]]> tags?

Comment: @Lee No problem. Have a look at [`DOMDocument::createCDATASection`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createcdatasection.php).